# Add spaces to Text View

Tags: swift, uitextview, paragraph

I have an app that has a text field where I enter text though code. Here's an example:

```
var text = ["This is the text that appears in the Text View."]
```

I want to know how I can add paragraph spaces in the Text View through the code. Such as the text view says this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing
>   pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
>   aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
>   laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

But, I want to add a paragraph space like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing
>   pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
>   aliqua.
>
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
>   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Could you help me with this?

iOS app using Swift 3 and Xcode 8

Comment: NSMutableAttributedString and NSParagraphStyle should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using static text in the app, you can simply use the `newline` characters along with the text `"\n"`.
If it is dynamic / entered by user, then also you can check for new line character in `textView delegate method` and can add addition new line characters as you want.

Also, as in the comment above you can use `NSParagraphStyle` and can set `paragraphSpacing` (The space after the end of the paragraph) and `paragraphSpacingBefore` (The distance between the paragraph’s top and the beginning of its text content) properties to get desired spacing.

```
let paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paraStyle.paragraphSpacing = 20

let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paraStyle]
yourTextView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: yourText, attributes:attributes)
```